# Prevent ng-include content from pre-loading until toggled to show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Here is my code currently:

```
<!-- main.html -->
<div ng-controller="MainController">
  <button type="button" ng-click="toggleImgView()">Show Images</button>
  <div ng-show="showImg">
    <ng-include src="'myTemplate.html'"></ng-include>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- myTemplate.html -->
<img ng-repeat="src in images" ng-src="{{ src }}/>

/* part of MainController */
$scope.images = [...];
$scope.showImg = false;
$scope.toggleImgView = function () {
  $scope.showImg = !$scope.showImg;
};
```

When `main.html` is loaded, `myTemplate.html` is default to be hidden because of `$scope.showImg = false;`, then I can toggle to show it by clicking the `Show Images` button.

Although `myTemplate.html` is hidden, it is still loaded to the DOM. It contains a lot of images, which may result in heavy network traffic. Therefore, I don't want load it until the user click the `Show Images` button to toggle the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show` the DOM, and the directives (like `ng-include` in it) won't be inserted and compiled.

Comment: Just changed `ng-show` to `ng-if`, it works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case what myTemplate dom is loading before angular initialized.

ng-cloak might work here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Answer (score 0):

If you wait until the uses clicks the button before downloading the images, the user has to wait.

The idea of loading them asynchronously is so the user does not have to wait.

I would say don't try to prevent them from loading in the background, let them load. Then when the users wants to see them, they will be right there.

Comment: It is doing same thing now, but I prefer reducing the number of HTTP requests instead of enhancing the user experience, in case, most of the users may not need the `myTemplate.html`, so pre-loading may be wasted.

Comment: Ok, in some cases like yours, that may be a requirement, it's no problem as long as you can clearly articulate why many http requests are undesirable (server load, data charges, for example).

Answer (score 0):

If you set the images array to empty, then load the images into the array when the user clicks 'show images', that should solve that problem.

I agree with toddmo though - if the users have something to look at and the images are loading in the background, that's a better user experience unless you know you're in a limited bandwidth situation and are trying specifically to minimize the network traffic (i.e. edge mobile).